# How to colourise the text output in Standard ML?

Tags: unix, sml, smlnj, ansi-escape

This is the second week of my compiler course and I got an assignment to make a syntax highlighter. Since I am very new to Standard ML, I tried to print something like: `print("\033[1;31m hello world\n");`. In C/C++ this type of statement works fine, that is, it produces a colored output but in SML it just prints them. Please help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem probably is the `\033` escape sequence in octal notation. Octal numbers are a legacy feature of C-like languages that SML does not support. You can use either decimal (`\027`) or hexadecimal (`\u001b`) notation instead.

It's also worth noting that control sequences like the one you intend to use are not a feature of the respective language. Rather, they are interpreted by the *terminal* the program will be running in and output to. This one in particular is only understood by terminals with [ANSI / VT100 emulation](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences-vt-100.php).

Comment: Thanks for the information @Andreas, using `\027` instead of \033 resolved the problem.